# Azure Using shared access signatures for blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to implement shared access signatures when saving blobs (pdf files) to azure blob storage.
I want the link to the pdf file to expire after a set time, but it doesn't seem to be working.

The pdf creation and save process works fine, I create a pdf file and upload it to azure blob storage.
I can retrieve the blob URL and if I paste it into a browser, the pdf report shows up ok. It never expires though.

I set the expiry time to 2 minutes while Im testing (it would be around 24 hours in production). I can continue to view the report, nothing stops me.

I am new to shared signature access, but from what I've found so far, it is supposed to stop access after the specified time(is this correct?).

This is how I create the storage details (in the constructor of my class):

```
public BlobService()
{
    //use for local development testing
    _connectionString = Settings.AzureWebJobsStorage;
    this._container = Settings.ReportBlobContainer;

    try
    {
        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_connectionString);
    }
    catch (StorageException e)
    {
        throw;
    }

    // Get an account SAS token.
    string sasToken = GetAccountSASToken();

    // Use the account SAS token to create authentication credentials.
    StorageCredentials accountSAS = new StorageCredentials(sasToken);

    var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    chpBlobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(this._container);
    // Get the URI for the container.
    Uri containerUri = GetContainerUri();
    chpBlobContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(containerUri, accountSAS);

    try
    {
        if (chpBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists())
        {
            //leave the access to private only (default)
            // Enable public access on the newly created container.
            //chpBlobContainer.SetPermissions(
            //    new BlobContainerPermissions
            //    {
            //        PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
            //    });
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        var tmp = ex.Message;
    }

}
```

and this is how I generate the SAS token

```
private string GetAccountSASToken()
{
    // Retrieve storage account information from connection string
    //CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = Common.CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString();

    // Create a new access policy for the account with the following properties:
    // Permissions: Read, Write, List, Create, Delete
    // ResourceType: Container
    // Expires in 24 hours
    // Protocols: HTTPS or HTTP (note that the storage emulator does not support HTTPS)
    SharedAccessAccountPolicy policy = new SharedAccessAccountPolicy()
    {
        // When the start time for the SAS is omitted, the start time is assumed to be the time when the storage service receives the request. 
        // Omitting the start time for a SAS that is effective immediately helps to avoid clock skew.
        //Permissions = SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Read | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Write | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.List | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Create | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Delete,
        Permissions = SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Read | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Write | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Create,
        Services = SharedAccessAccountServices.Blob,
        ResourceTypes = SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Container | SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Object,
        //SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
        //just for testing the expiry works
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2),
        Protocols = SharedAccessProtocol.HttpsOrHttp
    };

    // Create new storage credentials using the SAS token.
    string sasToken = storageAccount.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);

    // Return the SASToken
    return sasToken;
}
```

I can see the blob from the Azure storage explorer, so the connection and generation process is fine, its just the expiry.

Can anyone help me out? I am clearly doing something wrong here.

Comment: It looks like the ACL for the blob container is not `Private`. Can you please check that? Also, if possible please share the SAS URL.

Comment: Another possible reason could be that the browser has cached the file. Please try with some other browser.

Comment: isn't it created private by default ?, this should create it as private if I'm correct chpBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists()  also I tried a different browser and its still accessible

Comment: I cant share the URL as its local development using the storage emulator

Comment: I would suggest checking the blob container ACL (just for peace of mind). In any case, share the SAS URL.

Comment: how do I check the blob container acl ?

Comment: when you say sas url , do you mean the blob url of my pdf file ?

Comment: this is the blob storage url   http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/reports/59a04c26-96d0-4e70-81c5-b4cfc2e35f34All_Trades_Activity.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151385/discussion-between-proteus-and-gaurav-mantri).

Comment: anyone help ? Ive tried all the suggestions but it never expires

Comment: If you're able to access your blob by `http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/reports/59a04c26-96d0-4e70-81c5-b4cfc2e35f34All_Trades_Activity.pdf` URL, that means your container's ACL is not `Private`.

Comment: so how do I set it as private ? I thought that was the default setting when creating the container ?

Comment: It is indeed a default setting. But I am guessing from your commented code that somewhere along the way you set the ACL as `Blob`. You can set it back to private by using `SetPermissions` method (again see your commented code after `CreateIfNotExists()` for that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Gaurav Mantri mentioned that it seems that your container is not private. There are 3 types of permissions for a container: public,blob,private. We could get more info from [Set Container ACL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-container-acl).

> The permissions indicate whether blobs in a container may be accessed publicly.
>   Beginning with the 2009-09-19 version, the container permissions provide the following options for managing container access:
>
> **Full public read access**: Container and blob data can be read via anonymous request. Clients can enumerate blobs within the container via anonymous request, but cannot enumerate containers within the storage account.
>
> **Public read access for blobs only**: Blob data within this container can be read via anonymous request, but container data is not available. Clients cannot enumerate blobs within the container via anonymous request.
>
> **No public read access**: Container and blob data can be read by the account owner only.

If the container is not private, we could set container ACL with [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) easily.

[image]

[image]

**Updated:**

By default the container permission is private, if we want to set permission for container programmatically. Please have a try to using the following code.

```
  container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions
                {
                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off //private
                });
```

Or please have a try to create a new container and try to create and use the SAS token to access the blob again.

**Update2 :**

Please have a try to test with following demo code, we also could get it from [Azure official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2), it works correctly on my side:

```
 var connectionString = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //UseDevelopmentStorage=true
 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
 CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
 CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("testcontainer");
 container.CreateIfNotExists();
 var sasBlobUri = GetBlobSasUri(container, @"C:\Tom\test.pdf");
 Console.WriteLine(sasBlobUri);
 Console.ReadKey();

 static string GetBlobSasUri(CloudBlobContainer container,string filePath)
 {

            if (!container.GetPermissions().PublicAccess.Equals(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off))
            {
                container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions
                {
                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off
                });
            }
            var blobName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            //Get a reference to a blob within the container.
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

            //Upload text to the blob. If the blob does not yet exist, it will be created.
            //If the blob does exist, its existing content will be overwritten.
            blob.UploadFromFile(filePath);

            //Set the expiry time and permissions for the blob.
            //In this case, the start time is specified as a few minutes in the past, to mitigate clock skew.
            //The shared access signature will be valid immediately.
            SharedAccessBlobPolicy sasConstraints =
                new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
                {
                    SharedAccessStartTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5),
                    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2), // 2 minutes expired
                    Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write  //Read & Write
                };

            //Generate the shared access signature on the blob, setting the constraints directly on the signature.
            string sasBlobToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);

            //Return the URI string for the container, including the SAS token.
            return blob.Uri + sasBlobToken;
    }
```

After 2 minutes I check from the incognito chrome window.

[image]

Comment: im confused as to how I would set this programmatically, I dont want public access to the container and i want limited read access to the blobs stored (24 hour expiry).  There seem to be so many settings

Comment: I have updated the code about how to set container permissions.

Comment: so how would I set readonly only access to individual blobs and then have the read access expire after 24 hours ?

Comment: can anyone give me a working example of how i would set an expiry date/time on each Blob I create and upload to storage ? I've looked at so many suggestions and nothing works, its got me really stumped

Comment: thanks for this, its cleared the whole thing up for me and i now now where Im going wrong, I've been taking the StorageUri.PrimaryUri.AbsoluteUri from the blob and using that to show the pdf in the browser, not the sas Blob Url.  Hopefully Ill get this to work now.  I am getting an error though this line of code if (!container.GetPermissions().PublicAccess.Equals(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off))  is giving me this error  'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'  the blob is created and stored ok but the getBlobsasUri method falls over

Comment: If it is useful, please mark it as an answer that will help more communities who has the same issue.

Comment: I think the problem with the 'Forbidden' error is down to UtcNow, this always reports the time 1 hour behind my computers time despite my date & time setting being UTC + 00.00.  The storage emulator is reporting all entries being one hour behind my system time

Comment: tried changing my system time to one hour behind and it made no difference, container shared access has these settings   Permissions = SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Read | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Write | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.List | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Create | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Delete,  so no idea whats going on here

Comment: Based on my knowledge, no need to change the system time. Please have a try to use my demo code to test it, it works correctly on my side.

Comment: Please have a try to test with a new created container to check whether there is difference.

Comment: I deleted the container, but it made no difference, as soon as I execute this line of code  if (!container.GetPermissions().PublicAccess.Equals(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off))  I get the forbidden error, drilling down into the exception message gives me this 'This request is not authorized to perform this operation.' so its down to permissions, but I really dont know what other permissions i can set

Comment: Ive changed my SharedAccessAccountPolicy to include these   Permissions = SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Read | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Write | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.List | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Create | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Delete | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.ProcessMessages,
                Services = SharedAccessAccountServices.Blob,
                ResourceTypes = SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Container | SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Object | SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Service | SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Container, - wont work

Comment: Im getting to the point of giving up now and just deleting the blobs from storage after 24 hours this seems like a whole lot of pain

Comment: I finally managed to get this to work, I simplified the way i created the container (without shared access signature) leaving everything to default and access to the blob now expires after the specified amount of time

Comment: Is there a way to get an already existing sas token for a container? (I wouldn't like to generate a new sas token every time an image request happens - or is it fine by Azure?)